# reload page using java script one time after 1 second

Tags: javascript, html, reload

some friends help me to write the following code to reload page once time after 1 sec but it had syntax error where i did not know.can any one help me to edit?

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
if(!window.localStorage.getItem("reload")) setTimeout(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("reload", "true");
    window.location.reload();
}, 1000)
});
window.addEventListener('unload',()=>{
window.localStorage.removeItem("reload");
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to describe what you've tried otherwise the answers will probably look like the answers to the other questions which you said did not help you, at best.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` doesn't change the hash

Comment: Reload the page with ``window.location.reload`` and set your timeout with ``setTimeout``

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if(!window.sessionStorage.getItem("reload")) setTimeout(() => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("reload", "true");
        window.location.reload();
    }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help.I use your code but the page refresh many times after 1 sec and don't stop. I need it refresh once time.

Comment: yeah, my bad, I didn't notice that, I edited the code for you.

Comment: thanks for your comment.is this code edited? because i have test it and it is same as before reload many times

Comment: I'll edit the answer again, using sessionStorage instead of localStorage